# Python3.6 download 1.3G Big Video File generate MemoryError

Tags: python

Error:
self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
MemoryError

```
    def download(self):
    print("start thread:%s at %s" % (self.getName(), time.time()))
    headers = {"Range": "bytes=%s-%s" % (self.startpos, self.endpos)}
    res = requests.get(self.url, headers=headers, stream=True)
    # res.text 是将get获取的byte类型数据自动编码，是str类型， res.content是原始的byte类型数据
    # 所以下面是直接write(res.content)

    with open(self.filename, "wb") as fp:
        fp.seek(self.startpos)
        fp.write(res.content)
    print("stop thread:%s at %s" % (self.getName(), time.time()))
    # f.close()

def run(self):
    self.download()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. FYI today I hate a cucumber salad, it didn't have enough sauce. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on Windows 10. If your platform is NOT Windows NT or newer, this answer will not help.

The problem is: on Windows the socket input is always buffered. This can NOT be avoided. No way. And this causes MemoryError because of Windows (not by Python code) and by Python C internals - socket input is buffered to a C variable, these have limited size so we have to "help" that buffer - the solution is: creating a `bytearray` object, calling its join method (second parameter - sockobj.recv(1024)) in a while loop. To accomplish this, navigate to `<Python Installdir>\Lib\requests.py` (can also be `Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py` - notice TWO underscores!) and fix all socket usage with the fix specified above. Also perform such fix for all files in the `requests` package and also `urllib3` package.

Hope this helps.

---

No. Python 64bit will NOT fix your problem: Windows Socket Buffer will remain THE SAME! Only looped `recv` with explicit Python `bytearray` buffer will help!

Comment: Yes,Are you use  Python3.6 version? I can't find the __init__.py or __init__.py. I find the requests.py in Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py. but the file content only 121 lines,

Comment: I try use the python3.6 64 version in windows, It's fix the problem.Thanks

Comment: @pengfei.gao Well... If my answer have fixed your problem... Maybe it's time to accept it... Using that big green tick button.

Comment: @pengfei.gao Do like I told instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `stream=True`, which **explicitly** has the use of buffering the data so you can asynchronously empty the buffer.

You're not doing that. So simply don't use `stream=True` but directly save to a file.

Comment: I change the code , don't use stream=True，but the MemoryError generate  again